# 2nd set of Tables not getting created after migration and seeding in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have been trying to add a 2nd set of tables to update the DB while using sequelize. The first set of tables got created in the DB without any problem. Migrating and Seeding went perfectly well.

But when I am trying to update the database with 2 more tables, even though in cli I am not getting any error but when I check in the DB the new tables are not there.
Undoing seeding also does not work.

I am wondering if I am missing any steps.

Any suggestions would be super helpful

Comment: have you checked the sequelize meta table in your database?  Are the tables you are trying to add listed?  If so delete them and see what happens.

Comment: No even in the meta table the tables are not listed, I am not even getting any error in migration and while seeding.

Comment: We need code to work against, what sequelize-cli commands are you running?

Comment: I am using sequelize for a project that I am working on and using it for the first time. I installed cli and initialize it. Then created the models with npx sequelize model:generate --name Task --attributes taskName:string, Sequelize cli has generated our models and the migration files, all fine until there, I created 4 models, then I migrated them npx sequelize db:migrate, done. I seeded it npx sequelize seed:generate --name task. The tables got inserted. I updated the date stamps in the js files, and npx sequelize db:seed:all.

Comment: I wanted to update the db with two more models, What I am observing is even though cli commands are running perfectly and migration files, seed files are getting created, when I go and check the db, I don't see any tables getting created

Comment: Was wondering if I am missing any steps?

Comment: Given what you told me I couldn't replicate the problem.  You will have to add more detail including what database you are using and hope or open a new question.  Since you didn't explicitly mention it have you rerun npx sequelize db:migrate to add the new tables?.  first you create the migrations  then you call migrate to make the corresponding tables then you create and run any seeds.

Comment: yes, I did run the command  npx sequelize db:migrate to add the new tables. Yes, I did the exact same steps, it's showing no error in the command prompt but two tables that I am trying to add rerunning the commands are not getting created. Using sqlite database.

Comment: it is not a connection problem, so if you don't have data to preserve or can move the data try eliminating seeding errors as the problem.  delete all entries in the schema table and rerun all migrations at once with no seeding.